# Setting document.documentURI to remote location

Tags: javascript, html, dom

How can I set the documentURI to a website of my choice. 
In a javascript function I have:

```
var sitePage = document;
sitePage.documentURI = "www.google.com"
```

Does not work, the URL stays on the original page.

Ideally I would like to click on an link in the page using its id:

```
sitePage.getElementById("link").Click();
```

But I get

> 'Type Error: cannot read property 'click' of 'null'

I have *"link"* and *"www.google.com"* as strings in 2 variables.

Comment: Firstly, `window.location.href = "www.google.com"`, secondly -> [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: I do know why the getElementById does not find the element it is because currPage is still reffering to the original page, even with  window.location.href = "www.google.com"

Comment: I think you're a bit confused there? Once you call `window.location.href` you leave the page, all javascript will be lost, and the browser moves on to Google, where you don't have access to ... anything, you can't run javascript on Googles pages.

Comment: I now, it is why I am trying to stay on my page but via document click on this link referenced by an id on the sitePage